# asp.net different view for logged user

Tags: asp.net, authentication, view

Let´s say, I have a button in my View. If the page is accesed by logged-in users it should be displayed normally. If it is accesed by non-loged (anonymous) user, I want the button not to be displayed.

The button visibility should not be affected by the user role, just by the fact if someone is logged in.

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. This condition is sufficient for this purpose:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <button>Send</button>
}
```